# Why after transaction to second fragment landscape mode showing me first transaction again?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 2 fragments. My first fragment have button which leads me to second fragment. It has this code:

```
binding.btnGet5Days.setOnClickListener {
            val forecastFragment = ForecastFrag()
            val transaction: FragmentTransaction =
                parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, forecastFragment)
                transaction.addToBackStack(null)
                transaction.commit()
        }
```

In my MainActivity i have this code:

```
val cityFragment = CityFrag()
        val fm: FragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        fm.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, cityFragment)
            .commit()
```

Fragments are in FragmentContainer,

The problem is when i'm joining second fragment through this button and turn my phone into landscape mode, my first fragment layering to my second fragment. How can i solve it? :)

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @mightyWOZ i thought i made not really hard question :/  how can i improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know without seeing your full code, but it's possible the code you posted from `MainActivity` is `add`ing a fragment on top of the existing stack. When you rotate the device, the `Activity` is destroyed and recreated, but the `FragmentManager` maintains its state so you don't lose everything. If your recreated activity code always adds a new fragment instance, you'll end up with what was already there, plus another `CityFrag` on top

The official recommendation is to use the [Jetpack Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) library, which will handle all that for you. If you don't want to go that far right now, you'll have to do your own checking and creation logic.

One thing you can do is to check if the `savedInstanceState` `Bundle` passed into your activity's `onCreate` is *null* - if it is, then this is a fresh start, and you can initialise with your first fragment. If it's **not** null, then your app is being recreated from some saved state, so you should probably let the `FragmentManager` take care of restoring itself and its back stack.

Otherwise take a look at [`FragmentManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager) - there's a bunch of useful methods like `getBackStackEntryCount`, `findFragmentByTag` etc. that you can use to work out what state your fragments are in, and if you need to add one or not. Depends on your code!

Comment: Looks like you're right. I will check this a little bit later. Thank you! Useful info anyway